# Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary is not allowed. (SQL)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Error:

> Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Any question? I am new to SQL Server

```
USE schemas
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE Table
    @LineaNegocioId INT,  --null
    @PaisId INT, -- required
    @AreaId INT, --required
    @Nombre VARCHAR(100), --required
    @Descripcion VARCHAR(100), --required 
    @fechaCreacion DATETIME, --required
    @fechaUltimaModificacion DATETIME --null
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    INSERT INTO Table (LineaNegocioId, PaisId, AreaId, Nombre, Descripcion, fechaCreacion, fechaUltimaModificacion)
    VALUES (@LineaNegocioId, @PaisId, @AreaId, @Nombre, @Descripcion, @fechaCreacion, @fechaUltimaModificacion)

    SET NOCOUNT OFF
END
```

Comment: Seems your proc takes a VARCHAR parameter but the corresponding column of table you're inserting into is a VARBINARY column.

Comment: The error message is self-explanatory. You do have a couple of varchar parameters so I can look on your columns definitions. Also try to edit your question to show something something anyone can copy and paste to actually test it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Either the field `Nombre` or `Descripcion` is a `varbinary` and you must explicitly `convert` those inputs for your `insert` clause.

It would look like this.

`VALUES (... ,CONVERT(varbinary, [@Nombre or @Descripcion]) ,...)`

Comment: try whit this now.

Answer (score 3):

```
drop procedure if exists sp_CrearUsuario
    go
    create procedure sp_CrearUsuario
    -- Parametros de entrada
        @_nom nvarchar(50),
        @pass varchar(max),
        @_correo nvarchar(50),
        @_cod Char(10),
    -- Parametros de salida
        @_mensaje varchar(100) out
    as
        /*declare @pass varbinary(max)*/
    begin   
            set @pass =(ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('contraseñaventas',@pass));
            insert into Usuario values(@_nom, Convert(varbinary(max),@pass), @_correo, @_cod) 
            set @_mensaje = 'Registro insertado'
            select * from Usuario 
    end
    go
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.